# Bind event handler to document & have access to firebase api data via useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

**Quick version:**

My ultimate goal is to do something like the link below but with an async call to firebase per `useEffect`  where the list data is composed of firebase object content.

https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-pxfy7

**Problem**

In the code below `useEffect` encapsulates code that pings firebase and gets some data back called "clients". The data is retrieved perfectly.

I then store that data using `useState` to two different instances of `useState`. The data is stored at `clientList` and `clientListForRender`.

So far so good.

Now the problem starts.

I have a third instance of `useState` that takes a number. I want to set a keypress event to the document so that I can use the up/down arrows to toggle the counter and access each value of the `clientListForRender` array.

When I set the eventListener I do not have access to the array (presumably due to the async calls not being in an order that allows for it).

I am not sure how to write my hooks in a way that gives me the result I want.

Thank you.

```
const clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
const [clientList,setClientListState] = useState([]);   
const [clientListForRender,setClientListStateForRender] = useState([]);
const [selectedIndex, updateSelectedIndex] = useState(0);



useEffect(() => {



  function handleKeyPress(event,arr){
    console.log(arr)
    if(event.key === "ArrowDown"){
      updateSelectedIndex((prev)=>{
          return prev += 1
      });
    }
  }



  clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
      const client = snapshot.val();
      client.key = snapshot.key;     //     __________________________1. get firebase data


     setClientListState(function(prev){       




           setClientListStateForRender(()=>[client,...prev]); //_______2 store data    



     // document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);  <---I am not sure where to put this. I have experimented and 
                                                                   // I decided to omit my cluttered "experiments" to protect your eyes


           return[client,...prev]
      });

   });


},[]);
```

Comment: What error do you see on console?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok there are few issues with the code you posted:

1) You should definitely not add your keyboard listener in the child_ added listener ( this means that every time the child_added listener is called, you are going to create a new listener, leading to unexpected results and memory leak)

2) You are calling setState in a setState updater function (the callback function you provided for,  setClientListState), which is an anti pattern and makes your code hard to follow and understand, and will cause unexpected effects once the component grows. If you want to update a state based on a previous state then use the useEffect callback

3) the useEffect function takes a second parameter, called array of dependencies. When you have provided it with an empty array, it means that you want your effect to run only once, which is problematic because we see that the function depends on clientsRef variable. ( from this actually comes your problem because the keyboard listener was having the old value of your clientsList which is the empty array, and so it was always returning 0, when keys where pressed, i explained more in the code sandbox)

4)You should return a callback function from the useEffect function to clean the effects you created, turning off the listeners you attached (or else you might have memory leaks depending on how much the component gets mounted/unmounted)

ok here is how the code should be to work:

```
const clientsRef = firebase.database().ref('clients');
const [clientList, setClientListState] = useState([]);
// I don't understand why you wanted another list, so for now i only use on list
// const [clientListForRender,setClientListStateForRender] = useState([]);
const [selectedIndex, updateSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

useEffect(() => {
  function handleKeyPress(event, arr) {
    if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
      updateSelectedIndex(prev => {
        if (prev >= clientList.length - 1) {
          return (prev = 0);
        } else {
          return prev + 1;
        }
      });
    }
  }

  clientsRef.on('child_added', snapshot => {
    const client = snapshot.val();
    client.key = snapshot.key; //     __________________________1. get firebase data

    setClientListState(function(prev) {
      return [client, ...prev];
    });
  });

  document.addEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);

  // here you should return a callback to clear/clean your effects

  return () => {
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', handleKeyPress);
    clientsRef.off();
  };
  // Its important to add these here, or else each time your keyboard listener runs it will have the initial value of
  // clientsList ([]), and so clientsList.length = 0, and so you will always updateSelectedIndex(0)
}, [clientList, clientsRef]);

//here render based on selected list as you wish
```

Finally i have set up a working codesandbox that emulated data fetching based on the example you give https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-4sn92, i added some comments there to help explain what i said above.

Comment: This crashed my app and created a recursive loop of some sort. I'll post more of my apps code soon so there is more context.

Comment: .... here is a video that shows the crash I get when I use your code. https://youtu.be/yDyYNgcceMs

Comment: Here is all my original component code dumped into a code sandbox just for viewing  without the firebase dependencies etc.  https://codesandbox.io/s/usage-5qj4u

Comment: @William its hard to see in a code posted in video ... the codesandbox you shared is not working at all ... i need a working codesandbox that show the problem, and from there i can take... Anyway you can add some dummy data to firebase and make it public for reading, and then use that data in the example you set

Comment: I created a thinned down version of the app with a dummy database and pushed it to Github with instructions. It's the best I could do. See if it helps:   https://github.com/wktdev/wm_troubleshooting

Comment: @William you can see code changes here https://github.com/wktdev/wm_troubleshooting/compare/master...sanehab:fix-hook?expand=1
basically what i did was working according to the points i mentioned above and nothing else :

I moved the child_added listener into its own effect, and added the creation of the ref at the up of the module ( If it is inside the component then that means that the effect is going to render each time, and since the child_added listener gets called always the first time with all children, this will cause all the children to be added, causing the loop you described)

Comment: Thanks, I am still getting a feel for the useEffect hook and I am looking at your example in parallel with the React docs. Your pushed code helped me much more than just the docs themselves!